# Can't make the right selection with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Drop-down won't load right using ajax, maybe because there is a conflict with the class(select_wrapper) that loads css, which maybe is called by a js script.

I have these 2 drop down menus:

```
<div class="select_wrapper">
                        <form action="" method="post" name="anunt" id="f_anunt">
                        <label><span>* </span><strong>Manufacturer:</strong></label>
                        <select class="select_5" name="marca" id="marca">                           
                            <?php
                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT id_marca, denumire FROM marci ORDER BY ordine");
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo ("<option value='".$row['id_marca']."'>".$row['denumire']."</option>");
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="select_wrapper">
                        <label><span>* </span><strong>Model: </strong></label>
                        <select class="select_5" name="model" id="model">
                            <?php                                   
                                $result = mysql_query("SELECT id_model, denumire FROM modele WHERE id_marca=1");
                                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo ("<option value='".$row['id_model']."'>".$row['denumire']."</option>");
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Here is the js code which works fine:

```
$("#marca").change(get_model);  
    function get_model(e)
{
    $.post("ajax_get_model.php",{id_marca:$(this).val()},function(data,status)
        {   
            $("#model").html(data); // pun modelele 
        });
}
```

And here is the php file that is loaded with ajax(after i make this select, in the dropdown that depends on the first one it goes to another select seen in "inspect elements" but in the dropdown i see one the first query):

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

$id_marca = $_POST['id_marca'];

$sir_sql="SELECT id_model, denumire FROM modele WHERE id_marca=$id_marca ";

if ($conn)
    {               
        $result=mysql_query($sir_sql,$conn);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))       
           echo ("<option value='".$row['id_model']."'>".$row['denumire']."</option>");

    }
    else 
        die('Incorrect:<br> ' . mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: can you expand on the question, not sure that is not working

Comment: if i was able i would upload a picture.. well, i cannot see the results on the dropdown from the file that i loaded with ajax

Comment: But if I go with Inspect Elements on that dropdown, the selected items are there, in different selected-option, out of the div

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your javascript, change it to this and try..

```
$("#marca").change(function(){
    $.post("ajax_get_model.php",{id_marca:$(this).val()},function(data,status)
    {   
        $("#model").html(data); // pun modelele 
    });
}
```

The way you were doing it, you weren't passing anything to the function and $(this) is out of the scope you were expecting. if you use an anonymous function like above it should work, alternatively pass $(this).val() to your get_model function and use the data passed. Either way u choose.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I found this Code:  jQuery('.select_5').selectik({
  containerClass: 'custom-select sell_select',
  width: 205,
  maxItems: 5,
  customScroll: 1,
  speedAnimation: 100,
  smartPosition: false
 });

If I comment it, my css on the drop downs goes away and it works fine. But I don't want that, I need that css.